# Array as my login credentials (for loop)

Tags: c#, arrays, authentication

I'm kind of new to all of these. Anyways I hope you guys could help me out a bit So here's my current code:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string[] usernames = { "user1", "user2" };
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= usernames.Length; i++)
            {
                if (textBox1.Text == usernames[i] && textBox2.Text == "password")
                {
                    Form2 frm = new Form2();
                    frm.Show();
                    this.Hide();
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    textBox1.Clear();
                    textBox2.Clear();
                    textBox1.Text = "Wrong credentials!";
                }

            }
        }
```

For some reason whenever I input a 'wrong' username and password it shows:

```
if (textBox1.Text == usernames[i] && textBox2.Text == "password") 

An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication2.exe
```

If there's a better way to code this (much simpler would be great). Please don't hesitate to post your own code. I just need a login form using arrays! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Use debug and you will see why

Comment: Logically walk through what happens when `i = usernames.Length`, since you're writing `i <= usernames.Length`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will try to check every users. since you have 2 it should loop 2 times but no. when you use .Length where

```
for (int i = 0; i <= usernames.Length; i++)
            {...}
```

it run 3 times for a length = 2
one for 0
another for 1
another for 2

since you do not have a username[2] (it start with 0) it will issue an error because you are trying to access and index that does not exists.

try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < usernames.Length; i++)
{...}
```

to run only two times. use always this for  (i < array.length) when you are using .length.

try this

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string[] usernames = { "user1", "user2" };
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool wasFound = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < usernames.Length; i++)
                if (textBox1.Text == usernames[i] && textBox2.Text == "password")
                {
                    wasFound = true;
                    break;
                }

            if (wasFound)
            {
                Form2 frm = new Form2();
                frm.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
            else
            {
                textBox1.Clear();
                textBox2.Clear();
                textBox1.Text = "Wrong credentials!";
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: GREAT!! I don't get error anymore! However, when i try user2 & password, I says wrong credentials. What am I missing? Thanks for the fast reply, good sir!

Comment: First you comparing user2 with user 1
not equal
it shows "wrong credentials"

later your are comparing user2 with user2
Is equal
break;

You could use a flag that indicate if you found what you expected at the for and if this flag is false after the end of the loop, THEN you show the error message

Comment: Please, @AnjoLiwanag mark my answer as correct if it is :D